# Pivot table rank by Name(Index) and Title(Column)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

The count represents the number of times they worked.

```
Title      Name    Count
Coach      Bob      4
teacher    sam      5
driver     mark     8
Coach      tina     10
teacher    kate     3
driver     frank    2
```

I want to create a table which I think will have to be a pivot, that sorts by count times worked, the name and title, so for example the output would look like this:

```
coach         teacher      driver
tina   10      sam 5        mark 8
bob     4      kate 3       drank 2
```

I am familiar with general pivot table code but I think Im going to need to use something a little bit more comprehensive.

```
DF_PIV = pd.pivot_table(DF, values=['count'], index=['title','Name'], columns=['title']
                      aggfunc=np.max)
```

I get an error `ValueError: Grouper for 'view_title' not 1-dimensional`, but I do not even think I on the right track here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.set_index(['Title', df.groupby('Title').cumcount()])
  .unstack(0)
  .astype(str)
  .T
  .groupby(level=1).agg(' '.join)
  .T)
```

Output:

```
Title    Coach   driver teacher
0        Bob 4   mark 8   sam 5
1      tina 10  frank 2  kate 3
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for unexpected indent, is there missing "(" somewhere?

Comment: @Raven Yep, at the start.  Missed it.  Thanks it is fixed.

Comment: This is perfect, is there anyway to sort each column by frequency of the count? the output is currently sorted by name alphabetically.

Comment: NVM - I sorted the original dataframe and then applied your code and that worked